# react-error-boundary catches error, but app crashes anyway

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have a view that contains a buggy component that I want to gracefully catch using react-error-boundary. The error is detected all right by react-error-boundary and the error handler renders its contents instead of those of the buggy component, but the app crashes anyway.

I have this in ErrorHandling.js:

```
class ErrorHandling {

  myErrorHandler = (error, info) => {
    // Do something with the error
    // E.g. log to an error logging client here
    console.log(`Error: ${error}. Info:`)
    console.log(info)
  }

  ErrorFallback = ({error, resetErrorBoundary}) => {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Something went wrong:</p>
        <pre>{error.message}</pre>
        <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
      </>
    )
  }

}

export default new ErrorHandling()
```

This in BuggyComponent.js:

```
import { Card, CardBody } from 'reactstrap'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const BuggyComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    throw new Error('This is an error')
  }, [])

  return (
    <Card className='text-center'>
      <CardBody>
        <p>This shouldn't show</p>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default BuggyComponent
```

This is my view:

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import BuggyComponent from '../componentes/auxiliares/BuggyComponent'
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'react-error-boundary'
import ErrorHandling from '../componentes/auxiliares/ErrorHandling'

const TestView = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Row className='match-height'>
        <Col sm='12'>
          <ErrorBoundary 
            FallbackComponent={ErrorHandling.ErrorFallback} 
            // onError={ErrorHandling.myErrorHandler} 
            // onReset={() => {
            //   // reset the state of the app
            // }}
          >
            <BuggyComponent />
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default TestView
```

And this is the error I get, at the right. The app crashes and I can't interact with it anymore.
[image: App crashes]

Comment: Seems to me you are doing everything correct, check you don't have somewhere else uncaught errors.

Comment: I think this is the normal behaviour of error-boundaries: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#component-stack-traces

Comment: Max, In the example you provide, the console message says that the error was indeed caught, and I'm sure the application doesn't crash. In my case, the console message says that the error was not caught and the window freezes :(

Comment: U Rogel, I'm showing you the whole thing. The line mentioned in the console message is the one that says "throw new Error('This is an error')" inside the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorHandling.ErrorFallback` is undefined. You either need to instantiate an `ErrorHandling` instance, or make `ErrorFallback` static:

```
class ErrorHandling {

  static myErrorHandler = (error, info) => {
    // Do something with the error
    // E.g. log to an error logging client here
    console.log(`Error: ${error}. Info:`)
    console.log(info)
  }

  static ErrorFallback = ({error, resetErrorBoundary}) => {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Something went wrong:</p>
        <pre>{error.message}</pre>
        <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```